# Forwarding tables in hosts

Tags: router, ip-forwarding-table

I'm an engineering student studying networking from Kurose's A Top Down Approach.  I got stuck on an exercise from chapter 5 (link layer) and wanted to fill in the gaps in my knowledge.

The exercise asks to describe the steps taken at each node in order to deliver the packet from host E to host A, assuming APR tables are updated. Here is the solution:

[image: The solution]

Here are my questions:

1) Why does host E need a forwarding table? I previously thought only routers had forwarding tables.

2) The book says that forwarding tables contain entries (X, I) where X is a network prefix and I is the interface the router should send the packet through. The first step of the solution implies that the forwarding table in E also maintains the next hop information. Do routers also do this? Does the book simplify the description of forwarding tables in that sense?

English is not my first language, sorry for any mistakes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Any host requires a routing table. At minimum it's the default route 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to the default gateway. Without a default gateway the host wouldn't know where to send non-local packets.

2) Routers also forward packets based on their routing table. Routing table entries contain (at least) the destination network address with mask and the next hop. The egress interface is the one able to talk to the next hop.

These are the essentials. In practice, this often gets more complex with details like interface, metrics (routing precedence), priorities, source of the routing entry (static/local, dynamic routing peer, ...), tags.

Comment: My understanding was that routers forward packets based on their forwarding tables, and that forwarding tables are based on routing tables. Are you using routing table as a synonym for forwarding table?

Comment: Also, just to make sure I got it right, do forwarding table entries contain the egress interface?

Comment: The forwarding table can be a processed form of the routing table or it's a more general term (for a SAT for instance), that depends on the implementation and context. Most often the routing table contains the egress interface, allowing multiple interfaces to the same subnet to be distinguished (by metric),

Answer (score 0):

Hosts have forwarding tables. The default gateway that is normally configured on a host is the default next-hop router.

Your host will have several networks. Even if it only has one NIC, it will have the 127.0.0.0/8 network built into it, and it may have virtual interfaces, e.g. tunnels. The host needs to be able to determine where to send a packet, and it uses its forwarding table for that.

Hosts with multiple NICs (or virtual interfaces) will have at least one entry in the forwarding table for each directly connected network. There may also be other entries configured  for non-directly connected networks so that the host knows to which interface a packet should be sent.